# Launch function at the end of another swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to launch the funcion "caricaImmagine" after the function "caricaLavori". In the code is clear that caricaImmagine need that caricaLavori finish to append item to an array.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725059/wait-for-asynchronous-operation-to-complete-in-swift) but I don't know how to implement it.

Here's the "newMethod" (called in viewWillAppear):

```
 func newMethod(){
    print("login: \(login)")

    let userFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserEntity")

    do {
        fetchUsers = try moc.fetch(userFetch) as! [User]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch person: \(error)")
    }

    do{
        let users = try moc.fetch(userFetch)
        if(users.count > 0){
            print("utente connesso")
            tableview.delegate = self
            tableview.dataSource = self
            let d_email = fetchUsers.first!.email

            caricaLavori(datore_email: d_email!)
            for i in 0...lavori.count{
                caricaImmagine(id_lavoro: lavori[i].id)
            }

        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "area_utente_segue", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }catch {}
}
```

If you want the other 2 functions I'll edit this post (both of them loads data from php script, both do an http request)

thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "both of them loads data from php script, both do an http request". That is a key piece of information.

On iOS you want to do network access asynchronously. That means that a function that submits a network requests submits that request and then returns immediately, before the request has even been sent to the remote server.

The solution is to write your methods to take a completion handler. The method invokes the completion handler once the task is complete.

Take a look at my answer in the thread below for code that includes a working example of using completion handlers:

[Storing values in completionHandlers - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235082/storing-values-in-completionhandlers-swift)

Note that that post (And the sample app it links to) was written in Swift 2, and will need to be updated for Swift 3.